# XML Introduction (Paper etc.)

Tags: xml

Does somebody know a good introduction to XML, optimally a paper? I've found lot of webpages, but no papers. It should be not too much pages and not too complicated. I don't want to write XML documents myself, I've only have to understand them. It's about code represented in a XML file. ;)

Thank you very much.

Comment: Well, it's quite simple: you write stuff between other stuff, something like `<stuffname>actual stuff</stuffname>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion [this](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/default.asp) would be very useful to you. It's not a paper, I know, but its a pretty good place to learn the basics and understand what XML is all about.